# Tables within a list - Reports

Tags: reports

I have a list for a monthly status reports. I allow copying and pasting from other places. I get a lot of tables that contain data. While it looks great on the list, it does not translate well to a report, whether its excel or access. Is there a way to get what I see in my list to translate into a report I can print or turn to a pdf?